# ASP.Net controls becomes unresponsive after a while of perfect function

Tags: html, ios, asp.net, linq, memory

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now, so I thought I ask you folks if anyone could offer any help/inspiration.

I have an ASP.Net application that runs inside another iOS App on an iPod atop of a barcode scanner.
So below are the steps.
1. Scan a barcode
2. Catch the barcode as a Querystring parameter on a page in ASP.Net application through the iOS App 
3. Search the product and display details on the ASP Page
4. User will enter Quantity and add the product to the stock

and go ahead with another product. They can have 300-400 product at a time.

Now when the no. of products scanned and added into the stock, reaches to 100 - 105, the qty textbox on the page and other controls like buttons, start to become unresponsive and sometimes totally frozen.
if I scan a new product, the page searches and displays the product fine but  I am not able to access the textbox to enter the qty.

I have contacted the iOS App developer and he has done some work to improve this from initially 70 to 105 scans. This is all for gen 5 iPod (500MB ram)
It even performs better when I use an gen 6 iPod (1 GB ram) and I can go upto 170-180 before the issue comes in to haunt me.
I have to kill and restart the iOS app to be able to work again.

I was using Linq in ASP.Net but I have replaced linq with simple sql reader etc and stored procs to keep it light. That did not help a great deal, may be about another 5 scans added before it freezes.
I have used the profiling in the VS 2012 and replaced the heavily performing methods/objects to reduce the bytes used

Is there a way that I can further optimize the page to help the situation?
I am not even sure if I am barking the right tree here.

Comment: UI thread freezes until the backend completes processing (i think). If the loal is large enough it takes a lot of time to finish and hence yur controls dont work

Comment: It does not come back to life even if I leave it for 30 mins. if it has any thing to do with load, it should finish in 30 mins. just a thought.

Comment: A new info is that I have tried to check the resource monitor while testing it, I dont see the anything unusual from start till it was frozen. The IIS worker process only added 2 MB on top of what it was using in the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have done all you can to reduce the resources of the ASP.Net client side page, You might squeeze a little performance out of it by running the pages through a minifier. As you mentioned the iOS dev was able to gain a pretty big increase in scan numbers it seems like the biggest resource overhead might be on the iOS side.

I am not familiar with iOS development but it seems your issue is entirely related to the hardware capacity of the device. There might be more tricks the iOS dev can use to try and force the scanner app to take priority, even close unneeded background processes when it starts.

Comment: Thanks Nick, it has been long since I posted this but just realized that I never updated you on this. It was in fact  a hardware issue and iPhone worked fine and that was the solution in the end.